# In IOS, how to get leaderboard rank in Google Play Games SDK?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-play-games

My english is little short. I attach Google Play Games to iPhone5. Everything is fine except leaderboard rank. When I attempt to get rank from leaderboard, It always return zero.
 Below is my code. What is problem?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [GPGManager sharedInstance].statusDelegate = self;  
}

- (IBAction)signInWasClicked:(id)sender {
    [[GPGManager sharedInstance] signInWithClientID:CLIENT_ID silently:NO]; 
}

- (IBAction)submitScore: (UIButton *)sender { 
    GPGScore* myScore = [[GPGScore alloc] initWithLeaderboardId:LEADERBOARD_ID];
    [myScore submitScoreWithCompletionHandler:^(GPGScoreReport *report, NSError *error){
        if (error) {
            // error
            NSLog(@"ERROR");
        } else {
            // Success. Score retern fine. score return right value but rank is not.
            NSLog(@"%@, %lld", report.highScoreForLocalPlayerAllTime.formattedScore,
            report.highScoreForLocalPlayerAllTime.rank);
        }
    }]; 
}
```

In Google developer's "[Leaderboard in iOS](https://developers.google.com/games/services/ios/leaderboards)" section, there is no mention about leaderboard rank. But in GPGScoreReport object, there is GPGScore object and in GPGScore object, score and rank value are on it. 
 Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

```
GPGLeaderboard *myLeaderboard = [GPGLeaderboard leaderboardWithId:LEADERBOARD_ID];
myLeaderboard.timeScope = GPGLeaderboardTimeScopeAllTime;

GPGLocalPlayerScore* localScore = [myLeaderboard localPlayerScore];
GPGLocalPlayerRank* localRank = [localScore publicRank];

NSLog(@"Current rank : %@", localRank.formattedRank);
```

I didn't try this code, but according to the class references, it should work fine. Let me know whether it works or not.

Also, put that code "after" submitting your score.

Comment: Thank you @EDUsta. Unfortunately, It return zero.